# "An illegal flyer has been detected" what does this message mean?

Tags: x-com-apocalypse

Suddenly the game pauses as if this message had some relevance or something that I have to know about.

> An illegal flyer has been detected.

[image]

It points me to this flying car from Psyke organization as you can see:
[image]

Does this mean something? Maybe certain organizations planning something? I thought there could be some alien movement in there but the Alien infiltration graph shows nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That means an organisation has launched an aerial attack on another organisation's building. Usually (and most likely in your case) it's gangs and their turf wars, but if an organisation is hostile to X-Com, it can attack you.

I don't think it involves the aliens directly, so unless you want to specifically protect whatever's being attacked, you can ignore those warnings.